# How to find entire circle and rectangle shape on image using php

Tags: php, image, geometry

I am doing project on [OMR answer sheet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_mark_recognition) reading project using PHP. The problem I am getting is that i can not find the entire filled circle. Also i have to find a 4 rectangle to check whether image is contradict or not on that rectangle finding angle and rotate that image.

> $thiscol = imagecolorat($image, $x, $y);

```
        $rgb = imagecolorsforindex($image, $thiscol);
        if($rgb['red']<50 && $rgb['green']<50 && $rgb['blue']<50)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
```

using this function i only get a pixel, I am not getting the whole circle.

Comment: What's an OMR answer sheet? Which entire filled circle? What's a *"4 rectangle"*?

Comment: I believe entire filled circle means that when he finds it he is only finding the top left pixel and he wants to find the "entire" circle, meaning coordinates that define it, like a radius and center point...